# Is there a way to connect and fetch data from MongoDb without Document in same setup

Tags: mongodb, symfony

Hi I want to create web services in symfony2.8. I have already symfony2.3.7 installed somewhere else and it has already a db name: demoDb that contain all data (document) collections around 50-100.

Now I just installed new symfony2.8.15 to serve for services. So is it possible to connect and fetch data from (demoDB) into new Symfony2.8.15.

So I installed FOSRestBundle and all necessary thing to work with webservices. So I created a Controller ServicesController.php in new symfony2.8.15

I want to fetch data from User dicument which is exist in another setup. But database already I have connected.

```
$user = $dm->getRepository('EduLoginBundle:User')->findAll();//But User Document is in another setup2.3.7
```

is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That should work, the database is separate to the application

Comment: But which I try to write the quiry. From New symfony:
$user = $dm->getRepository('Loginbundle:User')->findAll(); . it is asking me Loginbundle not define. Because it is in another setup. So how can I write the quiryes in controller to get data from mongdb.